# Make half the div one color using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need some help here. I am trying to create a page header with some trickiness to it. I need to have a container-fluid with the left half background blue and the right half white. I then need a h2 "Title" /h2 inside a ? container to center it in the 12 columns the title has a border-bottom which stretches the width of the browser though. Here is my code but again I know it is some what half done since I cant figure out the best way to get the 50% background color. I need this to work on IE8 to present and the rest of the major updated browsers.

I hope I can get an image in here for you guys. If not I will set up a bootply for my example.

[image]

Thanks ahead of time for your help.

```
<style>
.halfWrapper{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 0%, blue 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 100%);
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    }
.halfAndhalf {
    width:50%;
    background:blue;
    display:inline-block;

}
.halfWrapper h2{color:#fff; text-transform:capitalize; border-bottom:1px solid green;}

</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 halfWrapper">
            <div class="container halfContain">
                <h2>Case Studies</h2>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I tried this several ways and feel this may be the best solution. Here is what I came up with. I hope it can solve other peoples issues that are similar.

```
    <style>
.halfWrapper{
  /*background: linear-gradient(to right, @tmcDarkblue 0%, @tmcDarkblue 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 100%);*/
    background:@tmcDarkblue;
    display:block;
    padding: 120px 0 50px;
    }
.halfContained{
    background:#fff;
    display:block;
    padding: 174px 0 30px;
    }
.halfContained .col-xs-12{
    padding:0;
    }
.halfBorder{
    border-bottom:1px solid @tmcLightblue;
    padding:0;
    }
.style-one {
  border: 0px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #4EB2DF;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  margin-top: 0px !important;

}
.halfWrapper h2{color:#fff; text-transform:capitalize; border-bottom:1px solid @tmcLightblue; display:inline-block; margin-bottom:0;}
.halfContained h2{color:#fff; text-transform:capitalize; border-bottom:1px solid @tmcLightblue;}

    </style>


    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 halfWrapper">
            <div class="col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-5 halfBorder">
                <h2>CASE STUDIES</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-6 halfContained">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <hr class="style-one">
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I feel that `<hr>` is more elegant than using a blank heading. Not good for SEO and more lines of code too :P

Comment: Ashesh what about the edit I made. Is this better? The main reason I used two col-xs-6's and added background color this way was to avoid using so much browser specific css hacks. What do you think?

Comment: I am going to try again using a similar method of using colored columns like what I am trying to do above. I am open to a better solution but I am getting annoyed trying to find a workable solution using bootstrap.

Comment: The above answer is not keeping the right layout for all media screens. This makes this a less desirable solution. Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track, just change the class to `body` element.

For the fancy underling of the `h2` element I have combined `border-bottom` property and styled `hr` (horizontal rules) element.

`h2` here is an `inline-block` element, therefore the `border-bottom` element is present only for the length of the `h2` text. Margins for heading and horizontal rule have been modified to zero pixels.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, black 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 100%);
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}
/* couldn't find it in html
.halfAndhalf {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
*/

.halfWrapper h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #4EB2DF;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
.style-one {
  border: 0px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #4EB2DF;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 halfWrapper">
      <div class="container halfContain">
        <h2>Case Studies</h2>
        <hr class="style-one">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: omg really it was that easy or am I brain farting on a Tuesday!( I will try this asap. I can see right away that I cannot add this to the body since it is just this one particular page that will have this style of header.

Comment: I added a better screenshot image of the entire page and what I need. I tried the solution you added but I do not think it will work properly. I also need it to work for IE8 and above.

Comment: the new screenshot changes everything. you will have to take a different approach. I am thinking of something like this - a nav, then a container with 2 divs -one div having the text "CASE STUDY" and the second div again containing two divs and the respective boxes (divs again).

Comment: also there are workarounds to make `linear-gradient` work with old browsers (read IE8+)

Comment: I know the workarounds with linear-gradient which is why I did not include all of that code. I am trying something like what your talking about but I am not seeing how I can get that dumb border to stretch like it is in the pic... @Ashesh can you add any code examples of what you are trying to suggest?

Comment: that is a just a rough sketch I came up with, you should try your own so that you will be able to actually build it. If you get stuck, post a new question. I was able to emulate that underline effect to the `h2` element. Hope it's good enough.